# Accessing a property of an object that is nested inside another object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm trying to access a property of an object that is nested inside an object. Am I approaching it the wrong way, is my syntax wrong, or both? I had more 'contacts objects inside, but eliminated them to shrink this post.

```
var friends = {
    steve:{
        firstName: "Rob",
        lastName: "Petterson",
        number: "100",
        address: ['Thor Drive','Mere','NY','11230']
    }
};

//test notation this works:
//alert(friends.steve.firstName);

function search(name){
    for (var x in friends){
        if(x === name){
               /*alert the firstName of the Person Object inside the friends object
               I thought this alert(friends.x.firstName);
               how do I access an object inside of an object?*/
        }
    }
}  

search('steve');
```

Comment: As `x` is a variable, you need to do `friends[x].firstName`. `friends.x.firstname` would look for the literal key `x`.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 6):

It is either

```
friends.steve.firstName
```

or

```
friends["steve"].firstName
```

You don't need the for-loop, though:

```
function search(name){
    if (friends[name]) alert(friends[name].firstName);
}
```

Comment: A question on a similar topic; why can't I use the dot notation?

`//this works
function search(name){
    if(friends[name]){
        alert(friends[name].firstName);
    }

//this does not
function search(name){
    if(friends.name){
        alert(friends.name.firstName);
    }

}`

Comment: @brooklynsweb - the dot notation can only be used with constant strings known at the time the code is written.  It cannot be used with strings stored in a variable.  For names stored in a variable or argument, you use the `obj[varname]` notation.

Comment: @brooklynsweb To elaborate what jfriend00 wrote... if you write `friends.name`, how can JavaScript know if you mean a "field called (literally) *name*" or a "field named whatever it says in a variable `name`"? The bracket notation lets you specify that: `friend[name]` is a "field named whatever it says in a variable `name`", while `friend["name"]` is a "field called (literally) *name*".